# Expo app for react-Native "something went wrong" Error

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am starting out on react development with Expo, so I am trying out a few example apps on the expo site. https://expo.io/@exponent/floatyplane

When I try to load any of them on my Android I get an error

```
Something went wrong, Uncaught Error: Could not load exp://exp.host/
```

On an iphone

```
no experience found at exp://exp...

 Error while loading: No version of @exponent/ compatible with this version of exponent (SDK versions 13.0.0, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 and platform "ios"). (code 404)
```

Phones are a Galaxy S4 Active with Android 5.01, and an iphone 4s with IOS 9.01. The Expo app I am using is the expo app from the playstore and appstore. I attempted to set the "write over other apps" permission but I could not find it since my phone does not run Android 6xx

Comment: is your system and phone  on the same network?

Comment: yes, and it wouldn't matter since I am loading a stock example app from the internet

Comment: try searching the project within the expo app